# Show error page instead of error if server some error occured in backend or template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, ejs

If some error occured in template engine the error shows on the webpage. I want that if our server is running in production mode then a error page displayed instead of displaying our server's error.

I want to show :-

## SERVER ERROR

Answer (score 0):

You can use a config variable with the environment and render callback param to manage it. Something like this:

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res){
        res.render('index', {
            name: "Index", 
         },  function(err, html) {
            const error = config.environment === 'PRO' ? 'SERVER ERROR' : err; 
            err ? res.send(error) : res.send(html);
        });
 });
```